# Detail explanation of wordpress database fields and metatag list

Tags: database

I am trying to understand the  fields of various table and default list of metatags for the tables,  currently being used in wordpress. Though google is showing up various results , but I need a detail one with list.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

Answer (score 2):

The WordPress codex has a pretty good diagram for you http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

Comment: I need detail about each field and required inputs.. Eg in table ws_comment their is comment_kerma .. I have to lot of google to understand its significance. I also want to explore various metatags for various table

Comment: I don't think you'll find anything more complete than that.  You may find additional detail for some tables, [like this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/66082/4645) - but otherwise, you'll have to read the code.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bit of a subjective question - as you dont say what you are trying to do or why you need such diagrams. It would be better to ask a new question please.

There is a bit of a collection of diagrams, schemas and other related stuff here

[Looking for WordPress System Diagrams](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57996/looking-for-wordpress-system-diagrams/57999#57999)

And ... at the end of the day --- maybe you can write about your findings here to add to the knowledge.