# MySQL Query to Retrieve Category from wp_posts

Tags: posts, categories, mysql, terms

Using this query to retrieve all of my posts with a specific `post_type`

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type = 'product';
```

As described [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66080/how-to-find-out-wordpress-category-table-in-mysql) the category is not in the `wp_posts` table but in term tables `wp_terms` `wp_term_relationships` `wp_term_taxonomy`

Searching through all the tables for a category I had in mind, the only instance of a category I could find was in the `wp_terms` table which contains the following columns

- term_id
- name
- slug
- term_group

Looking for cross-references to this in other tables and somehow relate them back to wp_posts is posing some complications.

My thinking is `term_id` I should be looking for as it seems like a foreign key, but the only instance of that is in `wp_term_taxonomy`, and the only information I can find in the table related to my category (or rather `term_id`) is

- term_taxonomy_id
- term_id
- taxonomy
- description
- parent
- count

So the only information I can get from this is letting me know that my `term_id` `taxonomy` is a `product_cat` and in `count` tells me how many posts I have for this particular category.

Knowing a little bit about MySQL I know if there's any hope of doing this I need to modify my query and do a `JOIN` or two.

But I'm only finding very limited information on what exactly I can latch onto.

Here's the structure of `wp_posts`

```
 `wp_posts` (
 `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `post_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `post_content` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
 `post_title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
 `post_excerpt` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
 `post_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publish',
 `comment_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
 `ping_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
 `post_password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `post_name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `to_ping` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
 `pinged` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
 `post_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `post_modified_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `post_content_filtered` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
 `post_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `guid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `post_type` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'post',
 `post_mime_type` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `comment_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 KEY `post_name` (`post_name`(191)),
 KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
 KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
 KEY `post_author` (`post_author`)
 )
```

Is it even possible to modify my query to only retrieve `wp_posts` table rows for specific categories?

Comment: Why do you need to access this with straight up SQL when there is the WP_Query class that can do it for you?

Comment: Never heard of that. I'll look into it. I'm just messing around with mass editing my post_content in the wp_posts table on my localhost in my own PHP script outside of WordPress.  Then importing it back to my live site kind of thing.  Worked just fine till I needed to filter categories

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Figured it out. @belinus is probably the solution for you if you're looking to do this within WordPress.

As for just a raw SQL query you can play around with, I found this one, modified it a little bit and it returns all the products for a particular category.

There are three tables required to do this `wp_posts` `wp_term_relationships` and `wp_term_taxonomy`

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (307)
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
```

Just replace `307` with the `term_id` of the category you're looking to get results for. You can find this by searching in the `wp_terms` `name` column and it will return the term id associated.

You can also return multiple categories if you wish, just comma seperate them in the `WHERE` clause for example `WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (307, 450, 200, 99)`.

Comment: SQL knowledge is always a big plus+

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the `WP_Query` class. If all you're looking for is to grab all posts based on the category, you can do that using the ID or slug.

```
$args = array(
   'cat' => 1,
);

$new_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

OR

```
$args = array(
   'cat_name' => 'news',
);

$new_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

From there you write the loop as normal with one exception:

```
<?php if ( $new_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
   <?php while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) : $new_query->the_post(); ?>
      // Post Code Goes Here
   <?php endwhile; ?>

   <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    // No Posts Found
<?php endif; ??
```

You need to include the `wp_reset_postdata();` function call which will reset the `global $post;` back to the main query's value.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll accept this answer if I can't find a solution that doesn't depend on depend on the WP framework.  Want to look a little more into this you would think there would be some way to join the tables together through a manual query... but maybe not

Comment: What are you trying to access this with if not WordPress?

Comment: I'm just exporting the tables I need from WordPress, doing some heavy testing and experimenting with them on localhost.  Mostly to try and bulk edit the post_content column and bring it back to live.  Since post_content is just simply blocks of html code, the framework wasn't required (till now, maybe).

Comment: You could use the REST API potentially then.

Answer (score 1):

I created a query, you can use this to find all the categories related to

```
SELECT *  FROM wpra_term_relationships 
INNER JOIN wpra_term_taxonomy ON (wpra_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=wpra_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id AND wpra_term_taxonomy.taxonomy='category')
INNER JOIN wpra_terms ON (wpra_terms.term_id=wpra_term_taxonomy.term_id )
WHERE object_id='273960'
```

Just replace 273960 with your POST ID

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. It was about getting posts from a specific category (the title is a bit misleading).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Deepak Sharma, with your post I can do what I was trying to do!
I made some fix for it works. I tried liked your comment, but I can't because I don't have enough points!

```
SELECT * FROM wp_term_relationships INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy='product_cat') INNER JOIN wp_terms ON (wp_terms.term_id=wp_term_taxonomy.term_id ) WHERE object_id='61170'
```