# SQL query to retrieve the number of WordPress posts with all given categories

Tags: php, query, sql

I'm working on a WordPress blog filter function that shows all categories with posts. When the user clicks a category I want to show the number of posts at each categoryname that have the active category AND this category. Cat A (5), Cat B (7), etc
I've archived this with WPs get_post and some PHP but it takes several seconds, as I have >5000 posts.

That's why I need a SQL query to do it as the DB is probably much faster in calculating the number of posts with all given categories.

I found a SQL ([MySQL Query to Retrieve Category from wp_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/267600/mysql-query-to-retrieve-category-from-wp-posts)) by @bbruman that does almost what I need, but it checks only for one category ID or, if coma separated, for all posts that have ANY of the given category IDs.
I deed this to show return only posts that have ALL of the given category IDs.

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (307)
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a working example that only counts posts that are associated with both categories. This is tested with 3 posts, not 5000.

```
function count_posts_with_categories($cat_ids) {

    global $wpdb;
    $cat_count = 0;

    // A subquery to get all posts that are assigned to each category
    $subquery = "SELECT object_id FROM $wpdb->term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (" . implode(',', $cat_ids) . ") GROUP BY object_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT term_taxonomy_id) = " . count($cat_ids);

    // Use the subquery to count the number of posts that are assigned to both categories
    $cat_count = $wpdb->get_var(
        "SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM $wpdb->posts 
         WHERE post_status = 'publish' 
         AND post_type = 'post' 
         AND ID IN ($subquery)"
    );

    return $cat_count;
}

$cat_array = array(1, 2); // Replace with actual category IDs
$count = count_posts_with_categories($cat_array);
echo "Number of posts: " . $count;
```

Comment: You're a genius. Thank you! Works perfectly and is lightning fast.