# How to get a list of all posts and their categories?

Tags: posts, categories, database, sql, api

Basically I just need to have a table like this:

| Post title | Categories |
| --- | --- |
| Post 1 | Category 1, Category 2 |
| Post 2 | Category 2, Category 2.1 |
| ... | ... |

From [MySQL Query to Retrieve Category from wp_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/267606/64282) I successfully workout this query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM wpd9_posts
LEFT JOIN wpd9_term_relationships ON (wpd9_posts.ID = wpd9_term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wpd9_term_taxonomy ON (wpd9_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wpd9_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
GROUP BY wpd9_posts.ID
```

But I don't know how to make it better.

Ideally, I prefer to get it from the API, since I don't have SSH access to my hosting. But using SQL and export to a CSV or JSON file is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to export the data to a CSV or JSON file directly from the SQL query, you can use the MySQL `INTO OUTFILE` clause.

```
SELECT wpd9_posts.post_title, GROUP_CONCAT(wpd9_terms.name) AS categories
FROM wpd9_posts
LEFT JOIN wpd9_term_relationships ON (wpd9_posts.ID = wpd9_term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wpd9_term_taxonomy ON (wpd9_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wpd9_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN wpd9_terms ON (wpd9_term_taxonomy.term_id = wpd9_terms.term_id)
WHERE wpd9_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND wpd9_posts.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY wpd9_posts.ID
INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/export/posts_categories.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: is there a way to make this as an API rather than a CSV file?